# Issue initializing DB when run from PowerShell prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**The Issue:**
Perform the following steps to recreate the issue:

```
cd C:\Temp

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name init-db-issue

cd .\init-db-issue

# Download ASP.NET Core sample projects

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://codeload.github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/zip/main -OutFile main.zip

# Expanding takes a while

Expand-Archive -Path .\main.zip

cd .\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3

dotnet user-secrets set SeedUserPW Secret123!

# Drop the database in case it already exists

sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Q "DROP DATABASE [aspnet-ContactManager-02]"
```

At this point, do not load the project in vs or vscode. Simply run the project from a PowerShell prompt:

```
dotnet run
```

Here's what I get on my system:

```
PS C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3> dotnet run
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\ContactManager.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\ContactManager.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\ContactManager.csproj]
fail: ContactManager.Program[0]
      An error occurred seeding the DB.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'password'))
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'password')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user, String password)
   at ContactManager.Data.SeedData.EnsureUser(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String testUserPw, String UserName) in C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\Data\SeedData.cs:line 49
   at ContactManager.Data.SeedData.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String testUserPw) in C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\Data\SeedData.cs:line 26
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ContactManager.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3\Program.cs:line 35
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Temp\init-db-issue\main\AspNetCore.Docs-main\aspnetcore\security\authorization\secure-data\samples\final3
```

Note the following part:

```
fail: ContactManager.Program[0]
      An error occurred seeding the DB.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'password'))
```

Now, load the project in vs but do not run it from there:

```
Start-Process .\ContactManager.csproj
```

Run the app from the PowerShell prompt:

```
dotnet run
```

Now I don't get the message `An error occurred seeding the DB` and the DB is indeed seeded.

**Question:**

Why does the issue go away when we simply load the project into Visual Studio? I would expect the project to work fine when running it via `dotnet run` without needing to also run Visual Studio. Is this a bug? Or is it due to some aspect of how the project is setup?

The project can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/authorization/secure-data/samples/final3/appsettings.json#L3).

This project is the example used in the following tutorial:

- [Create an ASP.NET Core web app with user data protected by authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Your connection string (`"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"`) doesn't include anything about your identity.  Visual Studio may flesh this out for you.  Try adding something like: `Trusted_Connection=true` into your connection string (I don't know the format that PowerShell expects though)

Comment: @Flydog57,

The connection string does appear to have `Trusted_Connection` in it:

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/authorization/secure-data/samples/final3/appsettings.json#L3

Comment: @Flydog57 Oh, I see. You may be referring to `sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" ...`. That's only being used to drop the DB. The connection string in the project has `Trusted_Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Properties/launchSettings.json` does not exist.

See this comment:

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21668#issuecomment-795543707

Here's a minimal test case which demonstrates the issue:

```
cd C:\Temp

mkdir init-db-issue-new-app

cd init-db-issue-new-app

dotnet new webapp -o ContactManager -au Individual -uld

cd .\ContactManager

dotnet user-secrets set SeedUserPW abc

@"
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

namespace ContactManager
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
                               
            var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        
            var testUserPw = config["SeedUserPW"];

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", testUserPw);
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}

"@ | Set-Content .\Program.cs

dotnet run # abc is displayed

mv .\Properties\launchSettings.json .\Properties\_launchSettings.json

dotnet run # abc is not displayed
```